# QGIS Print Composer: Adjust layer size

Tags: qgis, print-composer, qgis-2.12

I´m using QGIS Lyon 2.12 and am trying to make a map in the print composer with the scale 1:25000 in A4 size. I have drawn the map layer, but the map only covers a small part of the A4 space in the correct scale. I´d like to resize the layer in print composer so that it covers more space, while retaining scale and aspect ratio. Is there a way to do this?

If not, is it possible to crop the page while keeping A4 proportions? Basically, cut away all the white areas.

Answer (score 2):

With select/move object tool, resize the map area to fill the A4 space, then be sure to type the right scale (1:25000) in the map properties again.
If you still have white areas, you can cut them with a software like GIMP (if you export the map as jpeg).

Comment: Thanks, I think I´ve got it now. So I just need to make sure that the part of the map area that I want to print is within the same border as the constant-size white A4 area?

Comment: yes @earthsalt that's it. Beware that if you have to print your map you need some margin on every side.